# Remove the backgrounds on site icons

Tags: feature-request

Is there any reason why beta sites have blue lines over solid white in their icon backgrounds? It looks jarring when placed next to other site icons that have a transparent background.

Area51 also has this problem. What is wrong with a big outlined 51?

[image]
[image]

It's especially noticable on non-white flair.

Comment: All beta sites have the "sketchy" theme which includes the "shaded" text and the "blueprint" background...but I see your point.

Comment: @tombull89 I think it looks fine on the actual site, just not the logos.

Comment: -1 I like the way it is now, it means I can see the icon on my bookmarks toolbar regardless of my browser theme.

Comment: @staticbeast Perhaps a strong outline then?